# How to open windows phone market page of my app programmaticaly in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

In WP7 and WP8.1 Silverlight I do it with this code

```
MarketplaceHubTask task = new MarketplaceHubTask();
task.Show();
```

But how to do it in WP8.1 WinRT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link to your app's page in the store [launch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx) a ms-windows-store protocol targeting your app's ID from its Manifest.

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:navigate?appid=[your app ID]"));
```

See [Link to your app in the Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn770213(v=vs.105).aspx) in the [Publish to the Windows Phone Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn770213(v=vs.105).aspx) documentation for more information.